# Regex throwing up sre_constants error

Tags: python, regex

I am parsing the following data structure:

```
var teamFixtures = new WS.Panel(fixturesConfig);
teamFixtures.load([300, [[883762,1,'23-08-2014','17:00',300,'Atalanta',0,777,'Pisa',1,'2 : 0','1 : 0',1,0,'FT','2014/2015','Coppa Italia','1',60,108,5433,11361,'ICI','it','it',0,0,0]
,[883062,1,'16-08-2014','17:00',300,'Atalanta',0,267,'Chievo',0,'3 : 0','1 : 0',1,0,'FT','2014','Club Friendlies','1',57,247,4117,8489,'ICF','it','it',1,0,0]
,[875534,1,'09-08-2014','17:00',300,'Atalanta',0,1501,'Spezia',0,'2 : 0','1 : 0',1,0,'FT','2014','Club Friendlies','1',57,247,4117,8489,'ICF','it','it',1,0,0]
,[875542,1,'06-08-2014','17:00',300,'Atalanta',0,8183,'Feralpisalò',0,'1 : 0','0 : 0',1,0,'FT','2014','Club Friendlies','1',57,247,4117,8489,'ICF','it','it',1,0,0]
,[875541,1,'06-08-2014','15:00',300,'Atalanta',0,7587,'Renate',0,'1 : 0','0 : 0',1,0,'FT','2014','Club Friendlies','1',57,247,4117,8489,'ICF','it','it',1,0,0]
,[848157,1,'02-08-2014','19:30',300,'Atalanta',0,302,'Nantes',0,'*0 : 0','0 : 0',0,0,'PEN','2014','Club Friendlies','1',57,247,4117,8489,'ICF','it','fr',1,0,0]
], [[865781,4,'31-08-2014','17:00',300,'Atalanta',0,76,'Verona',0,'vs',,0,1,,'2014/2015','Serie A','-1',5,108,5441,11369,'ISA','it','it',0,1,0]
,[865791,4,'14-09-2014','14:00',78,'Cagliari',0,300,'Atalanta',0,'vs',,0,0,,'2014/2015','Serie A','-1',5,108,5441,11369,'ISA','it','it',0,1,0]
]]);
```

I am using the following Regex to locate the opening string pattern then return everything in the list of lists:

```
regex = re.compile('var teamFixtures \= new WS\.Panel\(fixturesConfig\); teamFixtures\.load\([\d+, \[\[.*?\]\]?\)?;', re.S)
```

This is throwing up the error:

```
raise error, v # invalid expression
    sre_constants.error: unexpected end of regular expression
```

To me though it looks like I have escaped all the special characters in this expression so I can't understand why I am getting this message.

Can anyone see where I am going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: You forgot to escape the `[` near `\.load\([\d+`, but even if you escape it your regex is not correct.

Comment: @mpcabd ah yes, so i have, thanks. why, what else is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not escape the regular expression correctly - one opening bracket was unescaped. Remember that regular expression needs one set of escapes, and python strings another; if you do not want to use Python string escapes, use raw strings (r'').

A more working regex could be:

```
regex = re.compile(r'teamFixtures\.load\(\[\d+,\s*(\[\[.*?]\s*])]\);', re.S)
```

The special characters that you need to escape there are `.()[`; neither `=` nor `;` are significant for regular expressions, and indeed `]` does not need to be escaped either. If this regex matches, the double list is available as `match.group(1)` and (would be) readily loadable into python using `json.loads`, if only it were proper JSON.

Comment: There is no need to escape the closing square bracket. However +1 for the raw string that is the main error of this pattern.